# \hspace with variable input does not work correctly with \ExplSyntaxOn

Tags: spacing, expl3, latex3

Playing around with expl3 I came to the strange effect that `\hspace` does not work sometimes when used in a `\ExplSyntaxOn` "environment":

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn           % <= removing this will make the code work correctly

\newlength{\numberedlistitemspacing}
\settowidth{\numberedlistitemspacing}{s.}

\NewDocumentCommand{\invoiceitem}{mmm}
{
    #1 \hspace{\numberedlistitemspacing} & 
    #2 & #3 \\
}

\ExplSyntaxOff          % <= removing this will make the code work correctly

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{rcl}
        right & center & left \\
        \invoiceitem{1}{2}{3}  \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

This code behaves just as if the `\hspace` was not there. Removing the `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff` makes the code work perfectly.

However this is not possible all the time. Especially when expl3 syntax variables or functions are used...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a table cell ends, LaTeX does `\unskip` in order to remove spaces that may have been input.

With `\ExplSyntaxOn` your code is equivalent to

```
#1\hspace{\numberedlistitemspacing}&
```

and LaTeX duly removes the horizontal spacing.

Without `\ExplSyntaxOn` your code is

```
#1 \hspace{\numberedlistitemspacing} &
```

and just the standard space is removed, but you get a normal space more because of the one after `#1`.

Leaving spaces in the input when typing in a `tabular` is good. In the code for commands it may be bad. You should use

```
#1\hspace*{\numberedlistitemspacing}&
```

if not under `\ExplSyntaxOn`, which can be

```
#1 \hspace*{\numberedlistitemspacing} &
```

if `\ExplSyntaxOn` is in force.

The rule of thumb is

- use `\hspace*` for a space that's never removed;
- never leave spaces before `\hspace{...}` or `\hspace*{...}`;
- never leave spaces after `\hspace{...}` or `\hspace*{...}`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I do now understand that I need to use `\hspace*` if I want to make sure the space is not removed. However, why should you never leave spaces before or after? To make the code behave consistently with `\ExplSyntaxOn` and without?

Comment: @mrCarnivore You need `\hapace` (with `*` or not) when you want precise control of the horizontal space, hence you don't want other spaces around.

Comment: Good point. Thanks.